# Dojo EnhancedGrid and programmatic selection

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

Here's my problem: in my application I have a Dojo EnhancedGrid, backed up by an ItemFileReadStore. The page flow looks like this:

1. The user selects a value from a selection list.
2. The item from the list is posted on a server and then the grid is updated with data from the server (don't ask why, this is how it's supposed to work)
3. The new item is highlighted in the grid.

Now, the first two steps work like a charm; however, the third step gave me some headaches. After the data is successfully POSTed to the server (via dojo.xhrPost() ) the following code runs:

```
myGrid.store.close();
myGrid._refresh();
myGrid.store.fetch({
    onComplete : function(items) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
             if (items[i].documentType[0].id == documentTypeId) {                                               
                 var newItemIndex = myGrid.getItemIndex(items[i]);
                 exportMappingGrid.selection.deselectAll();
                 exportMappingGrid.selection.addToSelection(newItemIndex);
             }
     }
      }
     });
```

Now, the selection of the grid is updated (i.e. the selection object has a selectedIndex > 0), but visually there's no response, unless I hover the mouse over the "selected" row. If I remove the .deselectAll() line (which I suspected as the culprit) then I sometimes end up with two items selected at once, although the grid *selectionMode* attribute is set to *single*.

Any thoughts on this one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setSelected(), like so

```
exportMappingGrid.selection.setSelected(newItemIndex, true);
```

The second parameter is true to select the row, false to unselect it.

Comment: I used setSelected and it appeared to work just fine until I ran into some trouble: if I select a row in the grid (by clicking the mouse), then add another row and select it programmaticaly I end up with two selected rows.

Comment: In a similar scenario, I found I had to do setSelected(xxx, false) to unselect the old row before programmaticaly selecting the new row.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
grid.selection.clear();
grid.selection.addToSelection(newItemIndex);
grid.selection.getFirstSelected();
```

Jon

Comment: but this works also:
    grid.selection.clear();
    grid.selection.setSelected(newItemIndex, true);